# How to fix 'ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected shape=(None, None, 20), found shape=(None, None, 2, 20)'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a few matrices that pass through multiple layers, the last one is Dense layer to produce a vector for each matrix. Now I wish to feed these matrices to an RNN of keras and that is where I face this error.

I tried stacking the vectors together in order to pass them to the RNN. Here's a piece of code for that idea:

```
input1 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input1)
input2 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input2)
out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack([x[0], x[1]], axis=1), output_shape=(None, 2, 20))([input1, input2])
out = SimpleRNN(50, activation="relu")(out)
```

And I receive:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  >>File "model.py", line 106, in <module>
    model = make_model()

  >>File "model.py", line 60, in make_model
    out = SimpleRNN(50, activation="relu")(out) 

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 532, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 440, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 368, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(x_shape))

>>ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected shape=(None, None, 20), found shape=(None, None, 2, 20)
```

And If I change the `output_shape=(None, None, 20)` in Lambda layer, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 >> File "model.py", line 107, in <module>
    model.fit([input1, input2], y_train, epochs = 15, batch_size = 20, verbose = 2)

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')

  >>File "/home/yamini/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

>>ValueError: Error when checking target: expected simple_rnn_1 to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Comment: What are shapes of `input1` and `input2`?

Comment: @giser_yugang both are of shape `(None, 20)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change `output_shape`,which should not contain `batch_size`.

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Lambda,SimpleRNN,Input
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = Input(shape=(20,))
input2 = Input(shape=(20,))
input1 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input1)
input2 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input2)
out = Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack([x[0], x[1]], axis=1), output_shape=(2, 20))([input1, input2])
out = SimpleRNN(50, activation="relu")(out)
```

Comment: I still get `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected simple_rnn_1 to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)`

Comment: @yaminigoel I'm working properly. Have you changed it? Can you give `print(out.shape)` after `Lambda`?

Comment: The shape is `model:  Tensor("lambda_1/stack:0", shape=(?, 2, 20), dtype=float32)`

Comment: Ok I have again copy pasted your code and it still happens to give the same error!

Comment: Actually when I run your code it doesn't gives the error but when I embed it in my code (`model.py`) it gives this issue. And I have no idea why so!

Comment: @yaminigoel The reason may be that the shape of your y_train is `(None,1)`, but the output of your model is  `(None,50)`. You should have given the complete model code.